Convert Timescaledb query to Clickhouse query
Following are the queries in timescaledb which i need to convert into clickhouse as clickhouse supports timeseries data as well
Following are the timescaledb queries:
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW 
 metadata5mins(
   ts,tws, counter_agg, measuringpointid, min, max, startingvalue, endingvalue
 )
WITH (timescaledb.continuous) AS
 
select 
 time_bucket('5 m', timestamp), 
 time_weight('LOCF', timestamp, value), 
 counter_agg(timestamp, value),
 measuringpointid, 
 min(value), max(value), first(value, timestamp), 
 last(value, timestamp)
FROM ds_measuringpointvalues
GROUP BY time_bucket('5m', timestamp), measuringpointid

and
select ts ,measuringpointid, 
    interpolated_average(tws, ts, '5 m',
        LAG(tws) OVER (PARTITION BY measuringpointid ORDER by ts),
        LEAD(tws) OVER (PARTITION BY measuringpointid ORDER by ts)
    ),
    min, max, 
    interpolated_integral(tws, ts, '5 m',
        LAG(tws) OVER (PARTITION BY measuringpointid ORDER by ts),
        LEAD(tws) OVER (PARTITION BY measuringpointid ORDER by ts)
    ),startingvalue
    , endingvalue, num_changes(counter_agg)
FROM metadata5mins;

Currently what i have achieved (min,max,first and last value for specified 5 mins interval):
SELECT 
    toStartOfInterval(timestamp, INTERVAL 5 minute) AS bucket_start,
    measuringpointid,
    assemblylineid,
    min(value) AS min_value,
    max(value) AS max_value,
    argMin(value, timestamp) AS first_value,   -- Similar to first(value, timestamp)
    argMax(value, timestamp) AS last_value  
    
FROM 
    ds_measuringpointvalues
GROUP BY 
    toStartOfInterval(timestamp, INTERVAL 5 minute), measuringpointid, assemblylineid;

Note: i want to calculate interpolated average,interpolated_integral for the specified interval.Please someone who has worked on timeseries data and has solved similar problem in Clickhouse help me in this.thanks
Currently what i have achieved (min,max,first and last value for specified 5 mins interval):
SELECT 
    toStartOfInterval(timestamp, INTERVAL 5 minute) AS bucket_start,
    measuringpointid,
    assemblylineid,
    min(value) AS min_value,
    max(value) AS max_value,
    argMin(value, timestamp) AS first_value,   -- Similar to first(value, timestamp)
    argMax(value, timestamp) AS last_value  
    
FROM 
    ds_measuringpointvalues
GROUP BY 
    toStartOfInterval(timestamp, INTERVAL 5 minute), measuringpointid, assemblylineid;

